# Problem with Getting value from database to my labels Access Database

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, select

Hello guys i need to show on my label words from my database and i have a problem, Its not working for me and its not showing the words...
I am using Select from And its not showing it...

```
        string connectionStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=F:\WordssTable.mdb;
    Persist Security Info=False";
    OleDbConnection connectObj = new OleDbConnection(connectionStr);
    connectObj.Open();
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
    command.Connection = connectObj;
    command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM WordsTable WHERE EnglishWord='" + hebw1.Text + "'";
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

## 2

```
    <form runat="server">
<div id = "Words">
<asp:Label runat="server" id="Engw"></asp:Label>
<br />
<asp:Label id="hebw1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label id="hebw2" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label id="hebw3" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label id="hebw4" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Your sample is incomplete. Did you execute the command? Did you use the data returned by the OleDbDataReader to update your labels? Please post a [mcve] to help us understand your problem

Comment: What i have to add bro?

Comment: You might want to consider [a DataSource control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/moving-to-aspnet-20/data-source-controls#the-accessdatasource-control) since you are working with webforms. The linked documentation mostly demonstrates using MS SQL Server but there is very little difference .

Answer (score 1):

First thing to do is to use the proper [*using statement*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) around disposable objects. Then change your command text to use parameters placeholders (@text) instead of string concatenations. (This should never be understimated. Parameters prevent parsing errors and sql injection hacks)

Now you are read to request an [OleDbDataReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader) and use it to fill your label with the data coming from the first record retrieved by the *OleDbDataReader*

```
string connectionStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=F:\WordssTable.mdb;
Persist Security Info=False";
using(OleDbConnection connectObj = new OleDbConnection(connectionStr))
using(OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand())
{
    connectObj.Open();
    command.Connection = connectObj;
    command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM WordsTable WHERE EnglishWord=@text";
    command.Parameters.Add("@text", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = hebw1.Text;
    using(OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        // Try to read the first record, if any, and then update the labels
        if(reader.Read())
        {
             hebw1.Text = reader["hebw1"].ToString();
             hebw2.Text = reader["hebw2"].ToString();
             hebw3.Text = reader["hebw3"].ToString();
             hebw4.Text = reader["hebw4"].ToString();
        }
   }
}
```

I assume that your record contains the column *hebwX* used by the reader indexer and none of this fields is null.

Answer (score 0):

your ptoblem is that you call command.ExecuteNonQuery() which returns only number of affected rows.
You need to change this to

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM WordsTable WHERE EnglishWord='" + hebw1.Text + "'";
OleDbReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while(reader.Read()){
  // set your label values here
}
```